# How to set data to the devexpress's treelist

Tags: c#, data-binding, devexpress, treelist

I have a treelist, I must to fill it with some data from text or excel file, also as possibility from class, please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It is really difficult to answer your question as it does not contain any specific information.  Anyway, the [Data Binding](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5553) topic provides the complete information on binding the TreeList to data.  I hope, it will be of some help to you.  If not, please give us more details about the task.